# How to emulate a high megapixel (MP) Camera in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-camera

I'm trying to set a Bitmap captured by the camera as the source of an ImageView.
It works on all my devices except on a Huawei p30 pro which has a 40 MP camera.

Is there a way to emulate a high megapixel camera in Android Studio in order to test if an app can handle the image size?

Comment: You can use your phone as emulator:                                                                https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app

Comment: Haha, thats what I was doing in the first place with the p30. The point is that as a developer I should be able to test my code without buying a multitude of phones to cover all differences. My team currently consist of at least 11 people that need access to a physical device and we have 6, where of 1 has a 40MP camera.
On top of that the Corona quarantine makes it impossible to pass it around.
Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Sadly no.
If you find a way please report back.